# Put all documents in an array

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way to push all the documents of a given collection in a array?
I did this but is there any quicker way?

```
var ops = [];
db.getCollection('stock').find({}).forEach(function (stock) {
    ops.push(stock);    
})
```

PS: I use Mongo 3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the [`toArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/) function on the [cursor](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/js-cursor/) that's returned from find, like this:

```
var ops = db.getCollection('stock').find({}).toArray();
```

Note: As with your original solution, this might suffer with performance if the `stock` collection contains millions of documents.

As an aside, you can use `db.stock` directly to shorten the query a little bit:

```
var ops = db.stock.find({}).toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [lean](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) query option. in your case: 

`db.getCollection('stock').find({}).lean()`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But this function is not recognized in Mongo 3.4.

Comment: if you're using mongoose 3.x or newer it should be ok. no problem with Mongo version.

Answer (score 0):

You could as well use [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) which will allow you to create the array on the server side - provided the resulting document array is no bigger than 16MB in which case you'll get an exception:

```
db.stock.aggregate({
    $facet: {
        ops: [ { $match: {} } ]
    }
})
```

In order to reduce the amount of data returned you could limit the number of returned fields in the above pipeline (instead of an empty [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) stage - which is a hack anyway - you would then use [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)).